# Jspinner show image from file

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I have a question about Jspinner, how to show image from jspinner?

In jspinner we will select image1, image2, image3...
at panel we will show image1 that is selected from jspinner from file.

[image]

Comment: Please, read this article https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think it's possible with a special model and a non-editable editor field.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy But `JTextField` doesn't display images - besides, for the amount of work, a label and a couple of buttons would be simpler :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer As I understood his question, he wants to display a string in the spiner and icon somewhere else.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy Okay, I'm just confused, there I thought they wanted a `JSpinner` to display images - but what do I know - besides, I was wrong, you can get `JSpinner` to do that :P

Comment: Ok brother. I will try...

Comment: thanks for your help ;)

Comment: I guess the other question is, what's wrong with the `JComboBox` you're using now?

Comment: may U can create it with JcomboBox ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add range of numbers to `JSpinner` then using if condition you can check for changing value.

In order to get changing value you can use `addChangeListener`

Below is the program I created to fit your scenario. I added comments to understand what happening there. You only have to do little changes there code and you can read comments and understand whats happening.

```
package stack;

import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Spinner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //for all the images you have
        ImageIcon icon, icon2;

        //here change image path to yours
        icon = new ImageIcon(new Object().getClass().getResource("/stack/Untitled-1.jpg"));
        //here change image path to yours
        icon2 = new ImageIcon(new Object().getClass().getResource("/stack/watermark.jpg"));

        //to display images
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setSize(300, 300);

        //if you want a image to show when window open
        //label.setIcon(iconName);
        label.setText("Switch");

        //create a jpanel to add the all component into layout
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setSize(300, 300);
        panel.add(label);

        //using spinner model you can change to fit your requirements
        SpinnerModel model = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, // initial value
                0, // minimum value
                2, // maximum value
                1); // step

        //create new spinner according to model that we create above
        JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(model);
        spinner.setBounds(100, 100, 50, 30);

        //crete jframe and add that panel we create before
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Change images from spinner");
        f.add(panel);
        panel.add(spinner);

        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);

        //To change images when changing values add ChangeListener
        spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                //when number changed get that number and convert into integer
                int count = Integer.parseInt("" + ((JSpinner) e.getSource()).getValue());

                //when spinner values change you can check using count and place image you want
                if (count == 1) {
                    //set image to jLabel
                    label.setIcon(icon);
                } else if (count == 2) {
                    label.setIcon(icon2);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Hope this is what you asked for.